# How to have multiple AND condition in sql statement?

Tags: mysql

i have query that will select the table columns

```
"Select tbl_products.item_category,
 tbl_products.images, 
 tbl_products.item_name,
 user_custom.mother_applicable,
 compatibility.motherboard,
 compatibility.form_factor
```

the tables and its columns and datas

**tbl_products**

```
item_category,     item_name,       images,
Motherboard        Asus_board      'BLOB data here'
CPU                Intel_pentium   'BLOB data here'
```

here at the **compatibility** table, the `item_name` of the `Motherboard` is also the `name` of the `Motherboard` in the **tbl_products**

**compatibility**

```
motherboard,   form_factor,
Asus_board     ATX Motherboard
Asus_board     Micro ATX Motherboard
```

**user_custom**

```
mother_applicable,
ATX Motherboard
```

the continuation of the code

```
FROM tbl_products, user_custom, compatibility
```

to specify where the columns to be taken from,

The explantion of how this thing will work 
now, the `WHERE` condition must be comparing if `compatibility.form_factor = 'ATX Motherboard' only those **Motherboard** names that is ATX in the compatibility will be output and will be equal to the same name in tbl_products

vote -1 if you don't understand sorry guys i just can't figure it out.
I'm still in progress of building this system http://g-ramcomputerhauz.com signup and login and start customize pc to understand what i meant, if you select the Micro ATX Case the next step in selecting motherboard should be empty because there's no motherboard added yet that is Micro ATX that can be fitted to the case..if you select the case where ATX motherboard can be fitted there will be an output of all the motherboard that is ATX in form_factor.. Thank you!

Comment: what should be the output? please provide sample of expected output.

Comment: Where is your join statements? You can't just list the tables in the from (technically, you can, but it's not what you want), you have to specify how they relate to one another. Also, your table design is poor. You should not relate records on a text field, but on a integer key.

Comment: What is your intended output? The products to populate the next choice?

Comment: I'm trying to think if this question could be expressed in a more confusing manner.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select tbl_products.item_category,
tbl_products.images, 
tbl_products.item_name,
user_custom.mother_applicable,
compatibility.motherboard,
compatibility.form_factor
FROM tbl_products, user_custom, compatibility
WHERE compatibility.form_factor = 'ATX Motherboard'
AND tbl_products.item_name = compatibility.motherboard
```

I'm sure there is a better answer if you use joins.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first join those tables and give condition in where clause

```
Select t.item_category,t.item_name, u.mother_applicable,c.motherboard,
 c.form_factor  FROM tbl_products t join compatibility c on (t.item_name=c.motherboard) join user_custom u join u.mother_applicable=c.form_factor
where c.form_factor = 'ATX Motherboard'
```